# Login Failure Error while trying to Debug T-SQL

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008, debugging

I'm trying to run the debugger on some T-SQL that lives inside just a new query (.sql).  I've never tried running the debugger on this server.  We log into this dev server with sa and I work remotely over vpn.

\When I try to debug, I get `Unable to start T-SQL Debugging.  Could not connect to computer 'servername'.  Logon failure: unknown user name or password.`

No idea how to resolve this.  I can run queries but just can't debug.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Debugging requires SSMS to be running as a Windows local or domain account, and the query window itself must connect to the server using Windows Auth, or a user in the sysadmin role. Since you say things like "remotely" and "vpn" I'm going to guess you're connecting to this server using a SQL Server login, not a Windows login. You might want to see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5237654/sql-server-management-studio-2008-runas-user-on-different-domain-over-vpn) to work around the vpn issue.

Comment: darn I was going to add that we log in using the local sa password.